# get record from object using Id in WHERE Clause

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, custom-object

I am trying to get the current record for editing using the below SOQL query but I keep hitting different errors like 'expecting colon, found recordId' or some such.

I have the current record ID from the parameters in a variable called `recordID` so I have tried:

```
recordId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

sObjectRFC = [select Id
        , Account_closed__c, Additional_information_comments__c
        , Anticipated_benefits_reason_for_change__c, Any_additional_comments_Data_Request__c
        , Any_additional_comments__c, Are_Customers_affected_by_this_change__c, Are_other_departments_affected__c
        , BOC_dormant_account__c, Building_Society_Act_dormant_account__c, Business_criteria_for_data_request__c
        , Customer_address__c, Customer_name__c, Customer_salutation__c, Data_analysis_by__c, Data_extract_analysis_Date__c

      from Request_for_System_Change__c where Id =recordId];
```

I have been trying this for a long time, also using `where Id:=recordId]` but no luck

What is the best way to do this?

Once I have that object `sObjectRFC` populated with the record my page will work.

Comment: Try `Id = :recordId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is: `where Id =: recordId`

To get the recordType name, you need to query for it using relationship fields

```
sObjectRFC = [select Id
    fld1, fld2, ...,
    recordType.name 

  from Request_for_System_Change__c where Id = :recordId];
```

I might suggest two handy references

1. [APEX SOQL and relationships documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SObjects_field_relationships.htm?search_text=getSobject)
2. [SOQL language reference manual - relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

You can discover relationship names using a varierty of tools, for example, Eclipse Force.com IDE Schema Browser

Comment: sorry @Boris, I was typing while you commented - you deserve this one as the answer

Comment: thanks - quick question, once I have a record in my object `sObjectRFC` how could I get the record type name into a variable? I have tried `recordType = sObjectRFC.recordType.Name;` but no luck

Comment: i updated my answer